# Assets Catalog ImageSet - Edit Contents.json

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode5, asset-catalog

I often use iPhone 2x image also for iPad 1x. By adjusting the layout the app still looks nice.

Asset Catalogs supports this, except for one little detail.
When I drag & drop an image to iPhone 2x and also to iPad 1x it creates a copy of the image.

I clean it up by editing Contents.json and delete the copy from the imageset.
Am I allowed to do this?

[image: shows content.json and file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the json-file does not help to reuse images and save disk space. If you build for pre iOS 7 you see that the image files are automatically generated and named in the app-bundle:

image~ipad.png
image~iphone.png
image@2x~ipad.png
image@2x~iphone.png

The main aspect of Asset Catalogs seems to improve the workflow between design and programming. It's a visual tool to structure your image data and care a little less about the naming. I heard of teams, in which designer works directly on the Asset Catalog.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be fine. The Contents.json file is valid and contains accurate information and the images all exist. These are the requirements that need to be met for the asset catalog to be valid.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to remove the copy and edit the json directly?  Surely sharing ipad 1x and iphone2x assets is a fairly common thing to do.